# Serializing fields in a custom DataSet to XML

Tags: c#, xml, serialization, ado.net, dataset

Is there any way to add fields to a DataSet which will be serialized along with the table information when the DataSet is serialized in XML? I have some information that describes the DataSet that I want to try to include inside it when I throw it around in XML. I've tried adding fields and classes in the partial class Visual Studio generates for you for validation methods but I can't seem to get them to show up alongside the table information in the XML file either when myDataSet.WriteXML() or I use an XMLSerializer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I haven't ever tried it, but the [ExtendedProperties](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.dataset.extendedproperties.aspx) property of DataSet is supposed to be just for this. It lets you store information which is persisted when the DataSet is serialised to XML.